# Photo gallery site

Tags: php, mysql, gallery, photo

I have created a basic website that uses MySQL and PHP to store the pages in a database following some online tutorial. The pages are used to dynamically create the menu , which I like. The main point of the site is to be an online gallery of paintings. 
I can easily create this site statically in HTML, but I kind of want to try doing it dynamically. I can store the jpegs in a folder on the server and have HTML links within the page content. But is there any other way of doing it? Would it be sensible to store all the picture data and file names in a database, so that it gets retrieved when a user clicks an option from the menu?
Any thoughts would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

1. Research a bit more, you have one of the most answered problem in existence.
2. Why do you want to do it dynamically if static HTML is sufficient for your use. To make it cool is not the right reason.
3. About storing the jpegs in database read this article.
   To BLOB or Not To BLOB - Microsoft Research
   research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=64525